# Count using Enhanced for loop

Tags: java, foreach

I have this code below, my goal is to count how many letter 'e' is in the String `"abcdee"`.

```
class Sample1 {
    String tiles;

    public Sample1 (String tiles) {
        this.tiles = tiles;
    }

    public int countLetter(char letter) {
        int a = 0;      
        for (char x : tiles.toCharArray()) {
            int m = 0;
            if (tiles.indexOf(letter) != -1) {
                m = 1;
            }
            a += m;
            System.out.println("Letter count is " + m); 
        }
        return a;
    }
}

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample1 s = new Sample1("abcdee");
        s.countLetter('e'); 

    }
}
```

I expect that the code would give me this result:

```
Letter count is 0
Letter count is 0
Letter count is 0
Letter count is 0
Letter count is 1
Letter count is 1
```

and then maybe add all the 1's to get 2. But all I get is this when I run it:

```
Letter count is 1
Letter count is 1
Letter count is 1
Letter count is 1
Letter count is 1
Letter count is 1
```

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: Are you meaning to print out the value of a instead of the value of m?

Comment: One-liner using streams: `return tiles.chars().filter(c -> c == letter).count()`.

Comment: @beat did you mean `Arrays.toStream(tiles.toCharArray()).filter(c -> c == letter).count()`

Comment: `tiles.indexOf(letter)` will output valid non negative index if `letter` is present in `titles`. in your code both are not changing during the loop execution. `abcdee` does contain `e` hence its printing like that

Comment: @JigarJoshi no, I mean [`CharSequence#chars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--), which directly gives you a stream of characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to fix your code is to change the logic in your counting method to

```
    int a = 0;      
    for (char x : tiles.toCharArray()) {
        if (x == letter) {
            a += 1;
        }
    }
    return a;
```

There are better ways, though.

You might want to look as [this old Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618205/counting-an-occurrence-in-an-array-java) which is a more general solution to the problem you are working on.

Comment: Thanks Ray I should have kept it simple... thanks for reminding me...you're a ninja.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The indexOf(String target) method searches left-to-right inside the given string for a "target" string. The indexOf() method returns the index number where the target string is first found or -1 if the target is not found. So if 'e' is present it would return true . 
You have not used variable x anywhere in your loop first of all .Maybe you can try ,

```
if (x == letter) {
  a+ = 1
}
```

instead of

```
if (tiles.indexOf(letter) != -1) {
  m = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's repeatedly printing `1` because you're using `indexOf` method, that means as long as the letter `e` exists within the string `tiles` it will always print *Letter count is 1*.To solve the problem at hand simply change:

```
if (tiles.indexOf(letter) != -1)
```

to:

```
if (x == letter)
```

An even simpler solution to return the letter count as of java-8 is:

```
public int countLetter(char letter) {
       return (int)tiles.chars().filter(e -> e == letter).count();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `chars()` when you apply a character-based filter anyway?